# Seeing $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos ax- \cos bx}{x^2} dx$ as a Frullani integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

$$
\implies I= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)-\cos(bx)}{x^2}\,\mathrm dx
$$
$$
\implies I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{1-\cos(bx)}{x}-\frac{1-\cos(ax)}{x}}{x}\,\mathrm dx,
$$
which is [Frullani Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral).
$$J=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}{x} dx=[f(\infty)-f(0)]\ln(a/b).$$ Here, $f(x)=\frac{1-\cos(ax)}{x},$ hence $I=0$, but $I$ is known to be equal to $(b-a)\pi/2.$

So the question is why $I$ in (1) cannot be treated as a Fullrani Integral?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$f(ax)-f(bx) =\frac{1-\cos(ax)}{ax}- \frac{1-\cos(bx)}{bx}\\
\ne \frac{1-\cos(ax)}{x}-\frac{1-\cos(bx)}{x}
$$

So, you may not apply the Frullani integral to $f(x)$ as you did.